# Resource File problem in VC++

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, resources, embedded-resource

When I try to build an application from a resource file I get an error. This is the error:

> "error RC2103 : unexpected end of file
>   in string literal "

--but if I comment out the

> "1 TYPELIB "File name.tlb"

in the resource file, my project builds well. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a typo in your question, the leading doublequote before **1 TYPELIB** looks like it could cause that error message and shouldn't be there?

Comment: How, to eliminate that.. then it will get created when ever i build